# Union of a Dependent and Independent Sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering what the linear dependency of the union of 2 sets would be.

1. Dependent union Dependent
2. Dependent union Independent

I'm thinking that the result of both would be dependent but could someone please clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent from the definition that if a set $S$ is linearly "dependent" and $G\supseteq S$, then $G$ is linearly "dependent".

Comment: To put it differently...if there's a linear dependence in $S$, then there's the same  linear dependence in any set that contains $S$. It's infectious.

Comment: what if they're not contained, and they're just separate sets..

Comment: If $G$ and $S$ are unrelated, nothing can be said aout $G$. Of course, $A\cup B\supseteq A$, though.